# No virtual method getLongVersionCode()J in class Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo

Tags: android, android-studio

On google play this **error**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.sonymobile.scan3d, PID: 13877
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getLongVersionCode()J
>   in class Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'android.content.pm.PackageInfo' appears in
>   /system/framework/framework.jar)  at
>   com.sonymobile.scan3d.ZipResourceManager.initializeExpansionFilePath(ZipResourceManager.java:100)
>     at
>   com.sonymobile.scan3d.ZipResourceManager.(ZipResourceManager.java:113)
>     at
>   com.sonymobile.scan3d.ZipResourceManager.init(ZipResourceManager.java:65)
>     at com.sonymobile.scan3d.Scan3DApp.onCreate(Scan3DApp.java:55)  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5822)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6572)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

show only on Xperia XZ1 Compact(Android 8.0) device test... I think this problem only worries me around the world, help me, I don’t know what to do with this bug

defaultConfig {

```
    applicationId "xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 23
    versionName "3.3"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: This error is coming from `com.sonymobile.scan3d`, which is Sony 3D Creator. That is not your app. Why do you think that this error is coming from your app?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [getLongVersionCode() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo#getLongVersionCode()), the method was added in API level 28, i.e., Android 9, therefore it is expected that the method does not exist on Android 8 devices.

The latest version of AndroidX Core contains the [`PackageInfoCompat.getLongVersionCode(PackageInfo)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/pm/PackageInfoCompat.html#getLongVersionCode(android.content.pm.PackageInfo)) method which works on all API levels.

Comment: I just set versionCode to 23 in build.gradle and I never call getLongVersionCode()...I found this in E:\Android_SDK\sources\android-28\android\content\pm\PackageInfo.java, then in E:\Android_SDK\sources\android-28\android\content\pm\VersionedPackage.java and in C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.core\core\1.0.1\ae10d2e1965b944830c2c2aaf154765ceb32e0bc\core-1.0.1-sources.jar!\androidx\core\content\pm\PackageInfoCompat.java(read_only)....so I have to fix these files ?I know how to get version of my game but 
how to get rid of this error -this is the hardest task

Comment: this error appears only on Xperia XZ1 Compact!!! maybe I should just exclude this model on google play?

Comment: The error should appear on every device before API 28, since the method shouldn't exist on any of them. Can you edit your question to include the full stack trace?

Comment: And this error don't shown on testing devices with android 4.3, 6.0,  7.1, 5.0....

Comment: Seems like an issue with `com.sonymobile.scan3d.ZipResourceManager.initializeExpansionFilePath` according to the stack trace.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Did you find a solution to this problem? I have exactly such a de problem. The error appears only on the Sony Xperia XZ1 Compact device with Android 8.0. On all other devices, the application works correctly (including on Android <9.0).

Comment: @Vergiliy - don't call methods that don't exist as part of the public API on that API level, it is as straightforward as that. None of the libraries mentioned in this question could provide that stack trace (it looks like code in the app itself), so switching the code over to the compat API as per my answer is exactly what you should be doing to get it working on all API levels and all devices.